# ¿Cómo generar un submenú con Bootstrap?

Tags: html, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Tengo un problema de diseño, he buscado varios ejemplos pero no han dado resultado, no sé si tengo que editar el CSS que tiene por defecto Bootstrap, necesito generar un submenú.

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen se muestra mi menú en el último `item` que es registro de gastos, quiero que se desplieguen más opciones, ahí debe ir mi submenú pero me sale de esta manera, quizás es por las clases de Boostrap que no las estoy utilizando correctamente.

Este es mi código del `item` vehículo, donde se despliega lo que se observa en la imagen:

```
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">        
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  <i class="fa fa-truck"></i> 
      Vehículos
    </a>      
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="registro_vehiculos.php">Registrar Vehículo</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="inventario.php" >Inventario</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="agregar_combustible.php">Cargas de Combustible</a>          
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="checklist.php">Checklist Resguardo</a>        
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="checklist_revision.php">Checklist Revisión</a>      
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="recordatorios.php">Recordatorios</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="reporte_factura.php">Reportes por Factura</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="reporte_fecha.php">Reportes por Fecha</a>  
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Registro de Gastos</a>
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li ><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
      </ul>               
    </div>
  </li>
```

Comment: Saludos que versión de Bootstrap estas usando ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proba con esto, reemplazalo en tú código:

```html
<li class="nav-item dropdown">        
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  <i class="fa fa-truck"></i> 
      Vehículos
    </a>      
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="registro_vehiculos.php">Registrar Vehículo</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="inventario.php" >Inventario</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="agregar_combustible.php">Cargas de Combustible</a>          
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="checklist.php">Checklist Resguardo</a>        
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="checklist_revision.php">Checklist Revisión</a>      
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="recordatorios.php">Recordatorios</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="reporte_factura.php">Reportes por Factura</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="reporte_fecha.php">Reportes por Fecha</a>  
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  <i class="fa fa-truck"></i> 
      Registro de gastos
    </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="registro_vehiculos.php">Second level link</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="inventario.php" >Second level link</a>
      </div>
                  
    </div>
  </li>
```

El resultado obtenido fue:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ya lo intente con el código que me proporcionas pero no se visualiza el texto en primera instancia el que dice registro de gastos aparece en blanco al darle clic ahí se ve el texto marcado en azul y luego despliega el submenu correctamente

Comment: Como se ve en la imagen es la salida que obtuve. Chequea el resto de tu código. Con que versión de Bootstrap estás trabajando?

Comment: la versión es 4.3 ok deja checo el código por que no se visualiza el texto hasta que doy clic en el espacio en blanco

Comment: Por lo que veo en tu menú original esta la opción 'Vehiculo' en blanco. Chequea los estilos que le estás dando a #navbarDropdown

Comment: si era eso es por los estilos que trae boostrap , una pregunta mas el submenu con que propiedad se puede desplazar a un lado que no sea hacia abajo

Comment: Podes cambiarle los estilos al div que contiene los 'second level link' con la propiedad margin-left : ancho del menu padre, se me ocurre

Comment: ok perfecto si ya solo es cuestión de moverle al css muchas gracias por tu tiempo y apoyo

Comment: @JasielTorres No es necesario modificar tu CSS para lo que requieres, ya existe una clase de BS4 que lo hace, se llama `.dropright` revísala aquí https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/dropdowns/#dropright

Comment: cierto ya lo acomode con esa propiedad muchas gracias por tu aporte